# core dump from Unix

Tags: linux, debugging, unix, gdb

on my debian installation , I have got some core dump:

```
$ file core.isc-worker0000.1456.90-001007-7474.1628261144.gz    
/core_dir/core.isc-worker0000.1456.90-001007-7474.1628261144.gz: gzip compressed data, max compression, from Unix, original size modulo 2^32 27582464
```

file show it is generated from Unix.
currently, I am not able to locate which binary it is generated from
Also not able to untar this file

```
$tar -xf /core_dir/core.isc-worker0000.13898.90-001007-7474.1628151435.gz
tar: invalid tar header checksum
```

What and how it can be investigated ?

Comment: gunzip and gdb.

Comment: file show it is generated from Unix so its hard to get which binary it is generated from ?

Comment: Run `zcat /core_dir/core.isc-worker0000.13898.90-001007-7474.1628151435.gz | file -` which will peek inside the compressed file to see what file type it is.